# How to use PhantomCSS with Protractor(Selenium) test cases?

Tags: selenium, protractor, phantomcss

I have using Protractor(Selenium) Test cases from past few months , We want to integrate UI Regression using PhantomCSS( with Baseline concept) also in our Protractor (selenium)Test Cases.

**Note:**

> (we are able to use Phantomcss but as side project using Casper But
>   not able to integrate it with already present Protractor test cases).